# Bounty and visibility for low-rep users

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3907570/259363) this month, and it didn't get much attention. I tried bumping it two times by adding a tag and by editing the title for something more fitting, but it still didn't draw much more people, so I ended up bountying it, this being my very first time.

However, despite sharing it elsewhere as well (Reddit, Discord), the question still remains mostly unseen. How is it so ?

I tried describing my personal work that led me to the question, about how to achieve the proof. There are two things I'm concerned about :

- How may I improve this question (and others in the future as well) so that they don't stay at the bottom of the cave ?
- For users with somewhat-low reputation, I find it punishing to have the bounty just vanish if no one answers in the valid period (in my case, the bounty was slightly more than 6% of my total reputation at the time of placing it). Do you think it would be a good thing to address this issue, that may (or may not, I'm unsure) make such users think twice before giving a bounty ?

Would an extended period of 7 more days for the very first bounty placed be a good idea ? Would refunding the very first bounty placed be a good idea (however, by placing a reputation minimum so that brand new users don't overflow the 'bountied questions' tab) ? Perhaps refunding the first placed bounty *if not awarded* would be a good compromise ?

Anyways. More specifically, in my case again, what should I do (and not do) to improve the visibility of my question ?

Comment: Related: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) (I guess that the suggestions given there are not exclusive to old questions.) You can also look at the [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).

Comment: Also, recently there was a post [extending the time period before bounties are awarded](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32781/bounties-dont-last-long-enough?rq=1)

Comment: At a glance, your question seems to be well-framed, even if I don't really understand the content. I think the main issue is just that it's at such a high level that few people are able to help in the first place. The questions that get answered here the fastest tend to be those at lower levels, difficulty-wise. The higher you go, the more you might have to wait, sadly.

Comment: If the bounty gets refunded when it is not awarded, you give a big incentive to **not** award the bounty. I don't think this would be a good idea.

Comment: @supinf I was mainly concerned about the first bounty, not about something recurrent ! It doesn't neither give an incentive to place a bounty at first if it concerns, say, 10% of your reputation, if you have the risk to have it vanish in the wild :) but I totally get your point, that's also why I was asking !

Comment: Your question has received quite a few views now (just under 200 at the time of this comment), but it still hasn't received an answer. You could try instead asking on MathOverflow and see if you have better luck there. (Although see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo) about crossposting.)